# How to send Parameter to an action, using formatter: 'showlink' in jqGrid 4.6.0 in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, parameter-passing

I have a column named " CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT " in my jqGrid .  and i want to make it a link that redirects to another action with sending parameter to that action. and I want to get this parameter from a different column of this  jqgrid . and of course i want the text to be the value of  CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT  that i get from database.

here is my Code :

```
{  name:'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT',index:'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT',edittype:'select'  , formatter: 'showlink'  , formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Home/Steps_Details/' , idName: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT' }   },
```

Everything is ok , I just can't send the parameter  to the action.
Maybe it will work with  "  addParam:  "  , but i don't know how to use it.

Thanks in Advance...

**UPDATE THE QUESTION :**

@Oleg Thanks for your solutions in comments, but I couldn't solve this problem. so i decided  to do it in another way like below codes:

```
 {  name:'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT',index:'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT',edittype:'select'  , formatter: 'showlink'  , formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '/Home/Steps_Details/' , idName: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT'  , addParam : "Contract_Req_Id= 123" }   },
```

And now the problem is that instead of 123(in my above code) I want to send the value of " CONTRACT_REQ_ID " of the current row to my controller  and don't know how to do this.

Is there  a way to save the " CONTRACT_REQ_ID " into a variable and then sending the variable as parameter to my action ?

Maybe something like this :

```
var myGrid = $('#list'),
selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
celValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'CONTRACT_REQ_ID');
```

But i don't know where to place it in my code.
My code is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#list').jqGrid({
        caption: "گزارش پیگیری قراردادها",
        url: '@Url.Action("Get_Contracts_Steps","Home")',
        datatype: 'json',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "Rows",
            page: "Page",
            total: "Total",
            records: "Records",
            repeatitems: true,
            userdata: "UserData",
            id: "Vahed_Descript",
            cell: "RowCells"
           // ,  data: { REQ_UNIQE: "REQ_UNIQE" },
        },
        mtype: 'GET',

        //columns names
        colNames: [' عنوان واحد ',
                            ' کد دبیرخانه ',
                            ' شماره درخواست ',
                            ' شرح درخواست ',
                            ' مبلغ برآوردی ',
                            ' تاریخ ثبت درخواست',
                            ' تاریخ تایید مدیر اجرایی ',
                            ' تاریخ تایید قائم مقام / معاونت ',
                            ' تاریخ ارسال درخواست به تدارکات ',
                            ' تاریخ اخذ استعلام ',
                            ' تاریخ ارسال پاکات قیمت',
                            ' تاریخ تایید بودجه- درخواست ',
                            ' تاریخ بازگشایی پاکات',
                            'تاریخ تایید صورت جلسه استعلام ',
                            ' تاریخ نامه احراز صلاحیت ',
                            ' تاریخ اخذ مدارک  ',
                            'تاریخ تهیه پیش نویس قرارداد ',
                            'تاریخ ارسال پیش نویس به دفتر  IT',
                            'تاریخ تایید پیش نویس توسط معاون',
                            'تاریخ تایید پیش نویس توسط مدیر',
                            ' تاریخ ثبت پیش نویس در سامانه کتاب ما ',
                            ' تاریخ تایید بودجه-پیش نویس ',
                            'تاریخ ارسال به ممیزی ',
                            'تاریخ تایید ممیزی',
                            'تاریخ تهیه نسخ قرارداد',
                            'تاریخ امضای شرکت',
                            'تاریخ امضاو ابلاغ قرارداد',
                            'شماره قرارداد ',
                            '',
                            ' نمایش جزییات ' 
        ],
        //columns model

        colModel: [
            { name: 'DESCRIPT', index: 'DESCRIPT', align: 'right'  },
            { name: 'DABIR_VAHED_CODE', index: 'DABIR_VAHED_CODE', align: 'right' },
            { name: 'CONTRACT_REQ_ID', index: 'CONTRACT_REQ_ID', align: 'right' },

            { name: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT', index: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT', edittype: 'select' 
                , formatter: 'showlink'
                , formatoptions: {
                    baseLinkUrl: '/Home/Steps_Details/', addParam: '&CONTRACT_REQ_ID=123' , idName: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT'
                  } 
            },
            { name: 'AMNT_TOT_ESTIMATE', index: 'AMNT_TOT_ESTIMATE', align: 'center',  formatter: 'currency',
                formatoptions:
                {  decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 0  }
            },
            { name: 'Req_Creation_Date', index: 'Req_Creation_Date', align: 'center'   },
            { name: 'Req_Exec_Confirm', index: 'Req_Exec_Confirm', align: 'center'  },
            { name: 'Req_Moavenat_Cnfrm', index: 'Req_Moavenat_Cnfrm', align: 'center'  },
            { name: 'SendToTadarokat', index: 'SendToTadarokat', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'GotEstelam', index: 'GotEstelam', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'SendPricePockets', index: 'SendPricePockets', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'Req_Budg_Cnfrm', index: 'Req_Budg_Cnfrm', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'OpenPockets', index: 'OpenPockets', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'ConfirmedEstelamSuratJalase', index: 'ConfirmedEstelamSuratJalase', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'EhrazSalahiatConfirmed', index: 'EhrazSalahiatConfirmed', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'GotDocs', index: 'GotDocs', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'Pre_Contract_Prepared', index: 'Pre_Contract_Prepared', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'sendprecontrtoIT', index: 'sendprecontrtoIT', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'PreContrConfirmed_Moaven', index: 'PreContrConfirmed_Moaven', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'PreContrConfirmed_Modir', index: 'PreContrConfirmed_Modir', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'SavePreCntrInKetabMa', index: 'SavePreCntrInKetabMa', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'Pre_BudgtCnfrm', index: 'Pre_BudgtCnfrm', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'SendToMomayeziDate', index: 'SendToMomayeziDate', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'Pre_MomayzCnfrm', index: 'Pre_MomayzCnfrm', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'ContrVersionsPreparedDate', index: 'ContrVersionsPreparedDate', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'CompanySignedVersionsDate', index: 'CompanySignedVersionsDate', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'ContrSignedDate', index: 'ContrSignedDate', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'CONTR_NO', index: 'CONTR_NO', align: 'center' },
            { name: 'REQ_UNIQE', index: 'REQ_UNIQE', width: 1, align: 'left', hidden: true },

            { name: 'Link', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                var x = '@Html.ActionLink("جزییات", "Steps_Details", "Home", new { REQ_UNIQE = "id" }, new { @style = "color:Blue;font-weight:bold;" })';
                return x.replace("id", rowObject[28]);
            }, align: 'center', width: 150,editurl: ' / Home / Steps_Details / '
            }, 

       ],

    pager: $('#pager'),
    rowNum: 300,
    rowList: [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800, 1000, 1200],
    sortname: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    altRows: true,
    shrinkToFit: false ,
    width: 'auto',
    height: '300px',
    hidegrid: false,
    direction: "rtl",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true,
    scrollerbar: true,
    loadComplete: function() {
        $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
    },
    loadError: function(xhr, st, err) {
        jQuery("#rsperror").html("Type: " + st + "; Response: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
    , loadonce: true

})

      .jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager",
         {
             edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true,   refresh: true
         })


      .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
          caption: "", buttonicon: "ui-icon-print", title: "خروجي پي دي اف",
          onClickButton: function () {

              $("#list").jqGrid('excelExport', { url: '@Url.Action("Get_Contracts_Steps", "Home")' });
          }
      })

    function toolbarSearching() {
        $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
            autosearch: true,
            stringResult: false,
            searchOnEnter: true,
            defaultSearch: "cn",
        });
    };



    $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        autosearch: true,
        stringResult: false,
        searchOnEnter: true,
        defaultSearch: "cn",
    });

    var maxNameLength = 10;
    $("input[id=gs_name]").blur(function () {
        var $th = $(this).closest(".ui-search-toolbar>th"),
            colIndex = $th[0].cellIndex,
            $colHeader = $th.parent().siblings(".ui-jqgrid-labels").children("th").eq(colIndex),
            colHeaderText = $colHeader.children("div").text();
        if (this.value.length > maxNameLength) {
            alert(colHeaderText + ' is longer than ' + maxNameLength + ' characters.');
        }
    });
    $('#gs_invdate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true
    }); 

})
```

Comment: Please include *always* the information, which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Additionally, you should include an example of URL, which you want to generate, for example `/Home/Steps_Details/aaa`, where `aaa` is the value from the column `'CONTRACT_REQ_ID'` of the same row. I can easy show how you can do this in case of usage "free jqGrid" fork, which I develop.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you so much for the answer. As you mentioned above i have edited the title of my question. I am using jqgrid 4.6.0 . I tried /Home/Steps_Details/aaa (in this version ) as you told me , but it didn't work. would you please show me how can i do this ? Thanks

Comment: jqGrid 4.6.0 is very old (almost 4 years old) and it's not supported since a long time. `formatter: 'showlink'` of the retro version don't allow you to create links with URLs like `/Home/Steps_Details/aaa`, where `aaa` is not const. You have to use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) if you really have to use the old jqGrid version.

Comment: I'd recommend you to consider to upgrade to the current version (4.15.2) of free jqGrid. You can see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.6.0...master) that almost 2000 commits are posted after 4.6.0. I try to hold free jqGrid fork compatible with old versions of jqGrid. Thus probably you don't need to change your JavaScript at the beginning of the migration. After that I'd recommend you to read [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) some [wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) articles and READMEs to know new features.

Comment: I'm now in business trip and I'm be at customer the whole day. I'll try to read your question at the evening from Hotel...

Comment: @Oleg Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did :

```
    { name: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT', index: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT', edittype: 'select' 
           , formatter: 'showlink'  , formatoptions: {
                    baseLinkUrl: '/Home/Steps_Details/', addParam: '&REQ_UNIQE=' , 
                      idName: 'CONTRACT_REQ_SUBJECT'
                  }
```